# How to evaluate $\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^r - 1}{3^r}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could someone help explain the solution step by step? Its quite basic but I don't understand why it's $3/2$.

$$\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^r - 1}{3^r}$$

Comment: This is an interesting question. Generally, the community here would be willing to answer your question when you show your work and provide explanations on the main problem/issue which bothers you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: hint : $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{r}-1}{3^{r}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{r}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{r} $

Comment: Negative of the series in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031781/evaluating-sum-k-0-infty-frac1-2k3k?noredirect=1), can be closed as duplicate ( I voted with incorrect reason so I cannot vote anymore).

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried.

Comment: Here's what gives it away: how do you add and subtract fractions? Now go backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can write

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{2^2-1}{3^r}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^r - \sum_{r=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{3})^r\\
&=s_1-s_2
\end{align}

Then since both ratios have absolute value less than $1$ you can compute the sum as follows for each term:

\begin{align}
s_1&=\frac{a_1}{1-r}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{2}{3}}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{1}\\
&=2
\end{align}

Finding $s_2$ is the same:

For $s_2$:

\begin{align}
s_2&=\frac{a_1}{1-r}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Thus $s_1-s_2=2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$. Hope this helps!!